# real time complexity of permutation DFS solution

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, depth-first-search

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/
common solution is DFS recursion

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0)
            return res;

        DFS(0, nums, res);

        return res;
    }

    private void DFS(int index, int[] nums, List<List<Integer>> res) {
        if (index == nums.length) {
            **//covert nums to list and add to res** o(n)
            return;
        }

        for (int i = index; i < nums.length; i++) {
            swap(nums, index, i);
            DFS(index + 1, nums, res);
            swap(nums, index, i);
        }
    }

    private void swap(int[] nums, int left, int right) {
        int tmp = nums[left];
        nums[left] = nums[right];
        nums[right] = tmp;
    }
}
```

from mathematics we can see there are total n! different permutations and many people say o(n!) is the time complexity

however from code we can see the recurrence is T(n) = O(n)(for add to permutation) + T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(2) + T(1) and I think O(n!) ignores O(n) for adding to permutation
I don't know how to generalize a big O from this recurrence, could anyone help.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean O(n)? There is a difference between O(n) and o(n). Why do you think that adding to `res` takes O(n) time? If `res` is a `LinkedList<T>`, it would be O(1), if it's an `ArrayList<T>` it would be O(1) amortised.

Comment: because we are adding a list to res.. so I think it is o(n)